# Running multiple browser instances in the same test spec

Tags: testing, protractor, pageobjects, end-to-end

If I have a single spec that is using page object model, how do I run multiple browser instance for that same spec?

For example I have spec:

```
it('should run multi browser', function() {
    browser.get('http://example.com/searchPage');

    var b2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
    b2.get('http://example.com/searchPage');

    var b3 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
    b3.get('http://example.com/searchPage');

    SearchPage.searchButton.click();
    b2.SearchPage.searchButton.click(); //fails here
    b3.SearchPage.searchButton.click();
});
```

How do I reuse vars declared in the `SearchPage` page object for the other browser instances?

Comment: Has the answer helped to solve the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really interesting question that is not covered in [Using Multiple Browsers in the Same Test](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/25aec6cac875b8b8e9a11a4cf5099c113359faa6/docs/browser-setup.md#using-multiple-browsers-in-the-same-test) or in the [`interaction_spec.js`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/25aec6cac875b8b8e9a11a4cf5099c113359faa6/spec/interaction/interaction_spec.js).

The problem with page objects is that page object fields are usually defined with a globally available `element` or `browser` which in your case would always point to the first browser instance. But you basically need to call `element()` using a specific browser:

```
b2.element(by.id('searchInput'));
```

instead of just:

```
element(by.id('searchInput'));
```

FYI, `element` is just a shortcut for `browser.element`.

---

I am really not sure whether this is a reliable solution and would actually work, but you can redefine [global `element`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/cf9a26f1b4bdca7d928794d24738786be074619a/lib/runner.js#L152) this way. Think about it as switching the search context to different browser instances:

```
SearchPage.searchButton.click();

global.element = b2.element;
SearchPage.searchButton.click();

global.element = b3.element;
SearchPage.searchButton.click();

global.element = browser.element;
```